# How to have application download and install upgrade?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, setup-deployment, auto-update

Is it possible for a Windows application to download and install a new version of itself *without* the use of a `Windows Service`?

How would this work when using `MSI` based installations?

If the app checked periodically for a new version, eg. once per day, could the new `MSI` be downloaded and then installed automatically so that it replaced the existing version of the app?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Installer is a Windows Service for installing applications on Windows.  It is included as a part of all current versions of Windows.  So you cannot install a Windows Installer package without running the service.

If the Windows Installer service was not installed on the system you would need to use a method of [Windows Installer Bootstrapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/122ea601-68a1-43c0-a8d1-42a881401ee1) to install the service.

Comment: Can the Windows Installer service be configured to check for application updates over the internet?

Comment: There is no Windows Installer parameter you can just set for periodic update checks. You could write a setup application to periodically check and then download the msi file and run the file using the service if there is an update.